# Azure Pipeline Deployment Fails - Error in changing file permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm using an Azure Pipeline to deploy to an App Service. I make it through the built stage, but am getting errors when deploying.

The deployment logs say "An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details."

Below are the errors in diagnostic log with system diagnostics turned on:

```
Error in changing file permissions : 124
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$app-dev:***@app-dev-django.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$app-dev:***@app-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

I've tried restarting both the deploy VM and the app service. I've also tried disconnecting the in the App Service Deployment Center before running the pipeline.

Comment: Can you go to the url  `https://$xxx:***@xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace` to check the trace log.  And you can check the application settings in Azure Web App. If possible, you can share the screenshot about the application settings with us.

Comment: Trace Log: 
Error occurred, type: error, text: No space left on device, stackTrace:    at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginWriteInternal>b__51_0(Object <p0>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

Comment: Application Settings:
"deployment_branch":"master",
"SCM_TRACE_LEVEL":"Verbose",
"SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT":"60",
"SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT":"7200",
"SCM_BUILD_ARGS":"",
"WEBSITE_AUTH_AUTO_AAD":"False",
"WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED":"False",
"SCM_USE_LIBGIT2SHARP_REPOSITORY":"0",
"ScmType":"None",
"FUNCTIONS_RUNTIME_SCALE_MONITORING_ENABLED":"0"

Answer (score 1):

> text: No space left on device, stackTrace: at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan1 source)

The cause of the issue could be that storage space of the App Service plan has reached the upper limit. It can be that the temp space in App service takes up too much space.

You can restart all the App Services present in that App Service Plan to clear out the temp space.

Or you can upgrade your APP Service Plan to get more space.